# How to edit screen grabbed video on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, video, editing, avi, capture

#### Problem

I've used [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) to record a presentation (fullscreen, 1280x1024, 45 min, no audio) to a small number of AVI files (10 files with about 800 MB total). Now I want to remove the initial and trailer sequences where you see start and stop of CamStudio. I'd like to remove some pauses during the video, too.

#### Question

Could you recommend some programs for Windows XP that I can use for this task? The result should be a (small - at least not bigger than the original) video format that I can play back. I've no need to create a DVD etc.

#### Already tried

I already tried [MAGIX Video Deluxe 16 (Trial Version)](http://www.magix.com/de/video-deluxe/), but it takes about 2 hours to just export 10 minutes of the video and produces about 2 GB of data for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For basic editing, how about the built-in Windows Movie Maker? If that won't suffice, [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) and [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) are both great for small editing tasks. Both support various different output formats.

VirtualDub and Avidemux are free and open source software.